# C++ Function Redefinition

Tags: c++, c++11

I keep getting a function redefinition error, and I'm not sure why.  I've looked through similar questions, but I couldn't glean any answers from them -- I've got header guards, and as far as I can tell, I have included the correct files and haven't redefined the functions outside of the header.  The errors are as follows:

```
Contact.cpp:188:2: error: redefinition of ‘communication::Contact::Contact(const communication::Contact&)’
Contact.h:35:3: error: ‘communication::Contact::Contact(const communication::Contact&)’ previously defined here
Contact.cpp:208:18: error: redefinition of ‘communication::Contact& communication::Contact::operator=(const communication::Contact&)’
Contact.h:36:12: error: ‘communication::Contact& communication::Contact::operator=(const communication::Contact&)’ previously defined here
```

The header and relevant chunk of the CPP file are below.  Any help is much appreciated.

Header:

```
#ifndef CONTACT_H
#define CONTACT_H

namespace communication {
        class Contact
        {
                char m_name[21];
                long long* m_phoneNumbers;
                int m_noOfPhoneNumbers;
        public:
                Contact();
                Contact (const char * c_name, long long contactList[], int numContacts);
                ~Contact();
                void display() const;
                bool isEmpty() const;
                void addPhoneNumber(long long phoneNumber);

                //Definitions of the functions causing problems
                Contact(const Contact& other) = delete;
                Contact& operator=(const Contact& other) = delete;
        };
}

#endif
```

CPP:

```
//Copy constructor
        Contact::Contact (const Contact& other) {
                strcpy(m_name,other.m_name);
                m_noOfPhoneNumbers = other.m_noOfPhoneNumbers;

                //Checks to see if the array being copied is empty
                if (other.m_phoneNumbers != nullptr) {
                        //Allocates the appropriate amount of memory to m_phoneNumbers
                        m_phoneNumbers = new long long[m_noOfPhoneNumbers];

                        //Goes through and copies the phone numbers to this.m_phoneNumbers from other.m_Phon$
                        for (int i = 0; i < m_noOfPhoneNumbers; i++) {
                                m_phoneNumbers[i] = other.m_phoneNumbers[i];  
                        }
                }
                else {
                        m_phoneNumbers = nullptr;
                }
        }
        //Copy assignment operator
        Contact& Contact::operator=(const Contact& other) {
                //Checks to make sure that the object is not being assigned to itself
                if (this != &other) {
                        //Copies name and number of phone numbers to the left operand
                        strcpy(m_name,other.m_name);
                        m_noOfPhoneNumbers = other.m_noOfPhoneNumbers;

                        //Deallocates memory that may have been given previously
                        delete [] m_phoneNumbers;

                        //Checks to see if the array being copied is empty
                        if (other.m_phoneNumbers != nullptr) {
                                //Allocates the appropriate amount of memory to m_phoneNumbers
                                m_phoneNumbers = new long long[m_noOfPhoneNumbers];

                                //Goes through and copies the phone numbers to this.m_phoneNumbers from other.m_PhoneNumbers
                                for (int i = 0; i < m_noOfPhoneNumbers; i++) {
                                      m_phoneNumbers[i] = other.m_phoneNumbers[i];
                                }

                        }
                        else {
                                m_phoneNumbers = nullptr;
                        }
                }

                return *this;
        }
```

Comment: you have marked them as delete which means compiler won't expect them. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Why have you deleted those functions?

Comment: Also, use std::string, not arrays of char.

Comment: I would love to, but this is for an assignment and we're not permitted to use strings yet.  Similarly, we're not supposed to modify what we're given in the headers -- hence the delete.  From my understanding, it's to keep client code copying/assigning to an instance of a class.

Comment: @clock If those functions are actually supposed to be deleted, simply don't implement them.

Comment: `long long* m_phoneNumbers`? Phone numbers aren't numbers. Don't store them as numbers. How would you represent the international access code (leading `001`)?

Comment: This is for an assignment -- there are certain requirements we have to stick to, and unfortunately storing phone numbers as an actual number is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your header file you've declared

```
Contact(const Contact& other) = delete;
Contact& operator=(const Contact& other) = delete;
```

as `delete` and then in your source (cpp) file you are trying to implement them which is an unexpected behaviour by the compiler. You should either remove the `delete` keyword in your header file, or remove their implementations from your source (cpp) file.